# clicking on a table cell reruns the jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wyDA/1/

I have it setup to when you click on a table cell it adds a textbox to it, but the problem I am having, is that you can't edit the text in the textbox once you click on the table cell I have tried `e.stopPropagation()` but that doesn't work.

Here is what is supposed to happen: 1) Someone clicks on the table cell, all other cells that have an input/textarea should remove the input/textarea and place the text back in the cell (works), 2) the clicked on cell should populate with an input/textarea with the text from the cell (works). Finally the user should be able to click on the buttons and edit the text in the input/textarea (doesn't work it keeps running steps 1 and 2).

```
$(".editable").click(function(e) {
    $(".editable").each(function() {
        if ($(this).has("input")) {
            var v = $(this).children("input.input, textarea").val();
            $(this).text(v);
        }
    });

    var type = $(this).attr("data-type");

    var val = $(this).text();
    if (type === "text" || type === "date") {
        str = '<input type="text" class="input" style="width: 100%;" value="' + val + '" /><br />';
    }
    str += '<input type="button" value="Save" />';
    str += '<input type="button" value="Cancel" />';

    $(this).html(str);
});

$(document).on("click", ".editable input", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: `e.stopPropagation();` does nothing when the event has already bubbled to the document.

Comment: To be sure I understand, your problem is that the save and cancel buttons don't work, correct?

Comment: @BradM so, what can I do?

Comment: @Derek no, I can't edit the text in the text field that displays

Comment: If you hilight the text it works, but I am seeing the problem if I just try to click.

Comment: @Derek it only works for me when I highlight the text in the input and then use the arrow keys to move to the end of the input box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead remove the separate click event for the input and check for the target element in the `.editable click` event itself..

```
$(".editable").click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('input')) {
           // your code when 
        }
        else {

           // something else
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the element with the .editable class from removing the input, by adding the following code to the start of your event:

```
$(".editable").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.className === 'input')
       return;
    //rest of code
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4wyDA/9/)

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:** Can you change your click event to double click? This will solve your problem. I mean something like this:

Instead of:

```
$(".editable").click(function(e) {
```

Use:

```
$(".editable").dblclick(function(e) {
```

Always when I see editable tables, they use double click.

[Your demo changed](http://jsfiddle.net/4wyDA/13/)